# Files remaining locked after writing using mount.cifs

Tags: cifs, rhel8

We have a server running RHEL 8.3 and connecting to a backup server running windows server running windows server 2016.  We connect from RHEL to server using the command:
mount.cifs \\SMCFILE\SMC$\Data$\picksaves /mnt/smcbackups -o user=user,pass="pwd",uid=uidvalue,gid=gidvalue,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777

We use that same command for other server running the same os, but just copy files around.

When doing the backups, sometimes the file will remain locked.  I suspect it has something to do with the file being held open.

If you log into the windows machine, it will say the file is locked by PID 4 or something.  If I disconnect the mount, it does not release it, so there must be a service handling the transfer(smb?) or something locking the file and will not release it until we kill it.

Is what we are doing the current proper way to mount a windows server file system on linux?H